# celery with django 1.3 KeyError: 'myproj.app1.tasks.add'

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm using django 1.3 with celery. I followed the instruction in  http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html
but old version django project structure is different, and it complains `KeyError`, below is the demo project *myproj* structure

```
.
├── app1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── mycelery.py
├── settings.py
├── urls.py
```

When I send a task from the web, it failed `KeyError: 'myproj.app1.tasks.add'`.
However it's ok when I send a task from `python manage.py shell`

```
>>> from app1.tasks import add
>>> result = add.apply_async(args=[1,2], countdown=30)
>>> result.ready() #wait for 30 seconds
True
>>> result.get()
3
```

Here is my code https://gist.github.com/dengshuan/a4adc7b690e101da0520

Comment: in your example, it should be `tasks` not `task`.

Comment: yes, i just corrected it

Answer (score 0):

`app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)` will register tasks in app1 directory as `app1.tasks.add`, tasks sent from shell will generate task with the same name. But tasks from web generates task named as `myproj.app1.tasks.add`. So it complains `KeyError`.

Changing `from tasks import add` to `from app1.tasks import add` solves the problem.

And if we follow this guide http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports , it fails with `ImportError`. This is because old django project structure. We should

1. change `app = Celery('myproj', backend='redis://localhost', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')` to `app = Celery('myproj', backend='redis://localhost', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', include=['myproj.app1.tasks'])`
2. comment out `app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)`
3. add project directory to celery `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.pardir))`

All these problems come from different task names from server and client side. We should make sure they are the same